Why iPhone's Phone app (contact section) is not importing UIDragItem with contact data ? (CNMutableContact)
I have contact data in my iOS app. I've created a CNMutableContact object and populated it with this data. Next, I created an NSItemProvider with this data and used it to create a UIDragItem. However, when I drag the contact view and drop it onto the Phone app (contact section), the contact does not get imported. What could be the issue here?
UITableViewDragDelegate's itemsForBeginning method.
First Attempt
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: any UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
        let contact = CNMutableContact()
        contact.givenName = "FIRST_NAME_LABEL"
        contact.middleName = "LAST_NAME_LABEL"
        contact.namePrefix = "MR"
        contact.note = "NoteContent"
        
        let dragItemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: contact)
        let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: dragItemProvider)
        
        return [dragItem]
    }

Second Attempt
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: any UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
        let contact = CNMutableContact()
        contact.givenName = "FIRST_NAME_LABEL"
        contact.middleName = "LAST_NAME_LABEL"
        contact.namePrefix = "MR"
        contact.note = "NoteContent"
        let dragItemProvider = NSItemProvider()
        dragItemProvider.registerDataRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.vCard.identifier, visibility: .all) { completionHandler in 
        completionHandler(self.getVCardData(fromcontact: contact), nil)
        return nil
}
        let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: dragItemProvider)
        
        return [dragItem]
    }

func getVCardData(fromcontact contact: CNContact) -> Data? {
        do {
            return try CNContactVCardSerialization.data(with: [contact])
        } catch {
            print("Error converting contact to vCard: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return nil
        }
    }


Phone.app is pretty minimal with integration (you can't even launch it with an empty tel: URL). Has Apple documented support for this? (I've done a lot with CNContact, but not with the UX features.
